# Как загрузить на git проект который имеет flavors?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

У меня есть проект который имеет 2 flavors один как бы premium и другой обычный. Если я загружаю этот проект на `github` то загружается только файлы из основной ветки.

Как загрузить полностью весь проект со всем содержимым всех `flavors`?

Вот я слепил проект для теста вот так выглядит структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно есть директории `debug` `main` `myone`

После чего я загружаю этот проект на `github` и загружаю его в виде `zip` обратно. Открываю и теперь структура имеет вот такой вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть только директория `main` нет директорий `debug` и `myone`

Если забыл, что то указать спрашивайте

Comment: Ну так флаворы есть в основной ветке локального репозитория или они где то в отдельной ветке? В любом случае наличие флаворов никак не влияет на работу гита.

Comment: И зачем выкладывать код с "premium" начинкой в открытый репозиторий?

Comment: @zTrap почему бы и нет если репозиторий приватный

Comment: @temq 1. какой смысл платить за закрытый репозиторий на github, если они бесплатны на bitbucket? 2."в открытый репозиторий? – zTrap 3 мин. назад"

Comment: @zTrap каждый выбирает инструменты из своих потребностей и предпочтений. На bitbucket репозитории "условно" бесплатные. Думаю рассуждения о выборе платформы для размещения кода выходят за рамки данного вопроса.

Comment: Расскажите подробнее как у вас устроено. Лично я видел только флаворы в виде типа в build.gradle. и они во всех ветках были одинаковы

Comment: не понятно в чем сложность? Такие проекты загружаются в репозиторий - как любые другие. Добавляете все папки с вашими flavors в индекс git-а и далее все как обычно.

Comment: @temq добавил описание в вопрос

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил описание в вопрос

Comment: @mit добавил описание в вопрос . Этот проект тестовый я его слепил и после чего инициализировал в нем гит, добавил `README` и все остальные файлы и потом выгрузил все и загрузил обратно. Результат описал в вопросе. Что сделал не так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, попробуйте к-л файлы поместить в папки для flavours. Возможно они не попадают в архив из-за того что пустые